# F# type inferencing

Tags: f#, type-inference

I'm working with fsharp type inferencing and I'm trying to understand how they work. Why is it that

```
List.filter List.head
```

is type `bool list list -> bool list list`?

Comment: What type did you expect it to have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List.filter` has the type (just enter `List.filter;;` in FSI):

```
> List.filter;;
val it : (('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list)
```

so it takes a `'a -> bool` and results in a `'a list -> 'a list`

Now you feed it with

```
> List.head;;
val it : ('b list -> 'b)
```

(it's another `'a` really so I renamed it) and now you have:

```
'a -> bool ~ 'b list -> 'b
```

you can unify this and see:

- `'b ~ bool` (from the right-hand-sides of `->`)
- `'a ~ 'b list ~ bool list` (from the left-hand-side)

but this all together and you get the answer F#`s type-inference gives you:

```
'a list -> 'a list 
~ ('b list) list -> ('b list) list 
~ (bool list) list -> (bool list) list
~ bool list list -> bool list list
```

Comment: sorry I am still having trouble understanding, what does ~ mean?

Comment: no problem (should have mentioned it) - it should indicate *type-equality* - it's a Haskell thing where you don't want to write yet another `=` ... so just read it as `=` for types here (for example: `'a -> bool` should be equal to `'b list -> 'b` because I plug in `List.head` into `List.filter` -  Now *functions-types are equal if the left-hand-sides and right-hand sides are* - thus I get that: `'a` is equal to `b list` and `bool` is equal to `'b`)